# AJAX on Rails doesn't work for me

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

So I have @line_items, which belong to @cart. I want to have my cart empty without refreshing page. I set button_to in cart template

```
<%= button_to 'Empty cart' , cart, :remote => true, :method => :delete,
:confirm => 'Are you sure?' %>
```

destroy method in carts_controller

```
def destroy
  @cart = current_cart
  @cart.line_items.destroy
  session[:cart_id] = nil
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to(store_url, :notice => 'Your cart is currently empty' ) }
    format.js
    format.xml { head :ok }
  end
end
```

and destroy.js.erb

```
$('#cart').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(@cart)) %>");
```

Works only after refreshing. I suppose, when button is pushed, cart is emptied, so when rails renders @cart it should be shown empty. Maybe I got something wrong?

Comment: Have you checked your AJAX op using the developer toolbar in your browser? Make sure its parameters are OK, it's a POST operation, it returns HTTP code 200, and any results (e.g. in XML) are correct.

Comment: You should add `format.js` above the `format.html...` line.

Comment: actually I have format.js in my code, sorry, I just posted version when I tried to do that through line_items controller

Comment: I changed destroy.js.erb to " $('#cart').hide() and it works. But when I create a new cart it still hidden. May be I can aslo make a js file for create method but I don't like this solution because it is not very good way of coding I suppose

Comment: ok, if destroy method also creates new empty cart in works, but is is a good solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found 2 ways of solving trouble

1) Which i consider better, adding :dependent => :destroy

```
has_many: line_items, :dependent => :destroy
```

to cart.rb model

2) Way with calling Cart.new in destroy method

Answer (score 0):

After the destroy action is called the @cart object maybe nil (if you're obtaining the current_cart by session[:cart_id]), so your JS partial can not render it correctly. Anyway you should really check your development.log to see what's really happening there.

Comment: as I sad it works if destroy method also creates new empty cart after destroying previous one, but I just wondering if it is good solution? I think you are wright, after destroying it is nill

Comment: If you're deleting a DB entry for cart and creating another it's not that good of a solution because you want to EMPTY the cart (remove all the line_items), not destroy it.

Comment: Actually Cart.new doesn't create new Cart, because of difference between "new" and "create" methods. Don't think that it matters to user, but I also do not consider that solution good.